# Can a mysql backup be transfer by copying and pasting data files from the mysql dir?

Tags: mysql, database-deployment

I need to reformat my computer and reinstall the OS.  I have plenty of databases that are connected to sites running on my XAMPP stack.  If I copy an paste the data files from the mysql folder into a new XAMPP stack, will the databases be preserved?  If so, which files need to be copied?  Are there other considerations?  Also, is there a difference if the destination stack is LAMP or WAMP?

Answer (score 0):

**I strongly advice you don't try to backup/restore a MySQL database simply copying the files.** 
Although that can be done with MyISAM tables, InnoDB tables won't work simply by copying files.

If you need to move the databases from one instance to another, I recommend you use `mysqldump` to create database backups.

Sugested reads:

- [`mysqldump` - A database backup program](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html)
- [Using `mysqldump` for Backups](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/using-mysqldump.html)
- [Copying MySQL tables, InnoDB tables not recognized (at dba.stackexchange)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58197/copying-mysql-tables-innodb-tables-not-recognized)